# Mysql import data contain commas with quotes

Tags: mysql

Hello i'm trying to import some data contain commas example

John,Locke,City of ,stars,87300
like you see City of ,stars there a comma on this column so added quotes
"City of ,stars" after that i used mysqlimport

`mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
            --fields-terminated-by=, \
            --local -u root \
            -p Database \
             TableName.csv`

**in that case the column City of ,stars has added like 2 columns i want keep only 1**

any help pls

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `fields-optionally-enclosed-by="\""` to your command line.

Comment: do you mean option
--fields-optionally-enclosed-by="\""

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks for that, @SmartJosef